# X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection está fechando a aplicação

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, certificado-digital, windows-10

Em um determinado cliente, ao acessar a função `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection` a aplicação está fechando sem nem mesmo passar no tratamento de erros.

Esta função abre uma caixa de dialogo do Windows para que o usuário selecione um certificado digital.

Estou utilizando .NET Framework 4.5, e o problema acontece numa máquina com Windows 10 Pro, que possui cerca de 8 certificados válidos.

Fiz uma aplicação de teste, para ter os logs e descobrir exatamente onde acontece o problema, e é ao usar a função `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iniciando a aplicação para seleção de certificado");
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new X509Store");
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        Console.WriteLine("store.Open");
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        // Obtém a coleção de certificados instalados
        Console.WriteLine("store.Certificates");
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

        // Excluí da coleção certificados vencidados, comparando a data corrente
        Console.WriteLine("collection.Find");
        X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

        Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection");
        X509Certificate2Collection certificados = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Certificados Cadastrados", "Selecione seu certificado", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

        Console.WriteLine("store.Close");
        store.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("certificados.Count");
        if (certificados.Count == 0)
        {

        }

        Console.WriteLine("certificados[0]");
        var teste = certificados[0];
        Console.WriteLine("certificados[0].Subject");
        var texto = certificados[0].Subject;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ex.Message");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finalizando");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que está provocando este erro?

Answer (score 0):

Guilherme, não sei se vc resolveu o problema, mas no meu caso eu mudei a linha:

```
X509Certificate2Collection certificados = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Certificados Cadastrados", "Selecione seu certificado", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
```

para

```
X509Certificate2Collection certificados = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Certificados Cadastrados", "Selecione seu certificado", X509SelectionFlag.**MultiSelection**);
```

A tela que abre é diferente, permitindo selecionar mais de um certificado, porém para a minha aplicação, ela sempre pega a primeira seleção e não tive problemas.